# Why can the meromorphic function only have finitely many poles in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

There is a proof in Complex Analysis by Stein-Shakarchi that I do not understand. I have highlighted it in red.

Why can they say that $f$ only has a finite number of points? What makes them able to exclude the countable number in the definition of a meromorphic function?

> [image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If $f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ is holomorphic in $0 < \lvert z\rvert < r$, then $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $\frac{1}{r} < \lvert z\rvert < \infty$ (and vice versa). Thus $f$ can have poles - except maybe at $\infty$ - only in the compact set $\overline{D_{1/r}(0)} = \{z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1/r\}$. Since the set of poles has no accumulation point, and every infinite subset of a compact set has an accumulation point, $f$ can have only finitely many poles in $\overline{D_{1/r}(0)}$, and possibly one at $\infty$, so finitely many altogether.

Comment: That is very nice!

Comment: This is much better than my answer. I was going to calculate the average volume of a Pole and the average interior volume of an aeroplane.

Comment: I just have one follow-up question please. I want to prove that the set of poles have no accumulation points as you said, but I get a little problem. So if $z_0$ is a pole, then I know that the function $1/f(z)$ defined to be zero at $z_0$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood. So I assume for contradiction that the set of poles has an accumulation point. Then I know that the function 1/f has an accumulation point for 0, so it must vanish everywhere in the domain. Now this says that f must have a pole at every point?, is this a contradiction?, if so why can not f have a pole et every point?

Comment: A meromorphic function attains finite values except in at most countably many points by definition, @user119615. So since the assumption that the set of poles had an accumulation point (in $\Omega$; it can have accumulation points on the boundary) led to the conclusion that $1/f \equiv 0$, or in other words $f \equiv \infty$, the assumption contradicts the premise that $f$ is a meromorphic function.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks!, but if I forgt the definition of meromorphic funciton and just look at the definition of a pole. Can then a function have poles in every point?

Comment: @user119615 No, $z_0$ is a pole of $f$, if there is a $k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ such that we have the identity $$f(z) = \frac{h(z)}{(z-z_0)^k},$$ where $h$ is holomorphic (in a neighbourhood of $z_0$) with $h(z_0)\neq 0$. So since $h(z)$ is by continuity nonzero on a neighbourhood $U$ of $z_0$, and $\frac{1}{(z-z_0)^k}$ is holomorphic and nonzero on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{z_0\}$, we have $f(z)$ finite and nonzero in $U\setminus \{z_0\}$. In particular, $U$ contains no other pole than $z_0$. Poles are by definition isolated singularities.

Comment: I have seen that identity in my book, the problem is that in the proof of that identity, they use the corresponding identity for order of zeros. So in order to prove that identity, you allready say that then 1/f can't be zero everywhere, and if you have allready assumed that then we can't have poles everywhere. But my problem is that they define poles like this :"A function defined in a deleted neighborhood of $z_0$ is a pole, if the function 1/f, defined to be zero at $z_0$, is holomorphic in a full neighborhood of $z_0$". Does this definition says that poles are isolated singularities?

Comment: What I meant first was that in order to prove the identity you gave me, they use a corresponding identity for the order of zeros. But in the theorem for the order of the zeros, the function (in our case 1/f) can not be zero everywhere.

Comment: By "defined", they mean "defined as a complex-valued function", so $f(z) \neq \infty$ in $U\setminus \{z_0\}$, since $f(z)\in\mathbb{C}$, @user119615. And that then gives you $1/f(z)\neq 0$ in $U\setminus\{z_0\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much for all the help!